# Update multiple fields on Google NDB entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Working with Google App Engine for Python, I am trying to create and then update an ndb entity. To update a single property, you can just access the property using a dot, e.g.

```
post.body = body
```

But I would like to know if there is a simple way to update multiple fields within an ndb entity. The following code:

```
class Create(Handler):
    def post(self):
        ## code to get params
        post = Post(author = author,
            title = title,
            body = body)
        post.put()

class Update(Handler):
    def post(self, post_id):
        post = post.get_by_id(int(post_id))
        fields = ['author', 'title', 'body']
        data = get_params(self.request, fields)
        for field in fields:
            post[field] = data[field]
        post.put()
```

The "Create" handler works fine, but the "Update" handler results in:

```
TypeError: 'Post' object does not support item assignment
```

So it seems I would need to access the properties using a dot, but that is not going to work when I have a list of properties I want to access.

Can someone provide an alternative way to update multiple properties of an NDB entity after it has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setattr`.

```
    for field in fields:
        setattr(post, field, data[field])
```

(Note that GAE objects do actually provide a hidden way of updating them via a dict, but you should use the public interface.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `populate` method:

```
post.populate(**data)
```